# How to make TopAppBar navigationIcon disapear?

Tags: kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

Some of my screens do not need the drawer so I want the navigation icon not to show on the topbar.  With the following code, I made the icon not shown but the space is still kept for the icon.  How can I eliminate it?

```
TopAppBar(
    title = {
        Text(text = title,
            textAlign = TextAlign.Start,
            fontSize = 18.sp) },
    actions = { TopbarActions()},
    navigationIcon = {
        if (needDrawer) {
            IconButton(onClick = {
            }) {
                Icon(Icons.Filled.Menu, "")
            }
        } else Spacer(Modifier.width(1.dp))
    },
)
```

Comment: Oh, didn't know there is a checkmark.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're creating an empty view, but you need to let `TopAppBar` know that there should be no view.

Pass `null` to `navigationIcon` like this:

```
TopAppBar(
    navigationIcon = if (needDrawer) {
        @Composable {
            IconButton(onClick = {
            }) {
                Icon(Icons.Filled.Menu, "")
            }
        }
    } else null
)
```

Comment: This works! If you pass an empty Box, Spacer, or anything else instead, the undesired blank space will still be there.